# UI-Router state includes property gets issue: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'StateDeclaration'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Before the state transition start, I need to check if the target state is under some parent state. The MatchCriteria looks like this:

```
this.transition.onStart({
  to: function(state) {
    return state.includes.parentstate;
  }
},() => {...
```

But I get an error saying `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'StateDeclaration'.`
If I `console.log(state.includes)` it does exist. Any ideas?

NOTE: The project use Angular 4 and UI-Router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `@uirouter/core`.  The object provided to the callback is a `StateObject` (which is normally considered an internal object).  The typings say that it's a `StateDeclaration` which is the object you used to register the state.

To work around this bug, declare your function parameter as `any`

```
this.transition.onStart({
  to: function(state: any) {
    return state.includes.parentstate;
  }
},() => {...
```

For backwards compatibility reasons, I think the next release of ui-router will simply update the typings to take a `StateObject`